# Objective c - float returning wrong value

Tags: objective-c, floating-point

I'm using objective c and trying to output a value from a function. Apparently I am doing something wrong because I'm receiving an incorrect value.

This is my code:

```
-(float) getAngleBetween {
float num = 0.0;
return num;
```

}

and I'm calling it as follows:

```
float *theAngleBetween = [self getAngleBetween];
NSLog(@"Angle.. = %f", theAngleBetween);
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float theAngleBetween = [self getAngleBetween];
//   ^
```

There should be no `*`.

Since you are returning a `float`, the receiver should have type `float` as well. `float*` means a pointer to float, which is entirely different from `float`.

BTW, make sure you declare `-(float)getAngleBetween;` **before** you call `[self getAngleBetween]`. Put it in the `@interface`. If it is not declared before, the method will be assumed to have the type `-(id)getAngleBetween;`. On x86 returning a `id` and a `float` use different API (`objc_msgSend` vs `objc_msgSend_fpret`), which may be the cause of wrong result.

Comment: I declared that in my interface and it still tells me that i have incompatible types in initialization.

Comment: @Lily: Have you `#import` the interface file ?

Comment: yes because I'm calling another function which i declared in the interface as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should have:

```
float theAngleBetween = [self getAngleBetween];
```

Get rid of the *, that's for objects only, float is a primitive data type.

Comment: without *, it tells me incompatible types in initialization